# Force the browser to use actual '\n' when it line breaks

Tags: javascript, css

I have an areatext box, and when a line gets too long, it wraps onto the next line. However, it does so without inserting a newline character into the text, and I need that newline character, so that the `element.scrollHeight` gets changed.

I can think of ways to do this in javascript, for example by taking the font-size along with the number of characters and insert `\n` appropriately, however I hope there is a simpler solution, maybe just a simple css setting?

EDIT:
Example:https://jsfiddle.net/ah126wm5/1/

Comment: would you like to give us some code ?

Comment: @John In this code, if I take the `scrollHeight` of the two different `textarea`'s, I will get two different heights, because the one where I pressed enter will have an actual `\n` appended. This is what I would like to have happen when I simply write a long line without pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS to *inject* a line break like that, you'll need script.

The reason is that a text that does not get line breaks manually, is supposed to adjust to its container width and that's why it behaves like that.

*Side note: The `textarea`'s scroll height still reports correct as you can see in this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/ah126wm5/2/), just add more text and check the height and you'll see it works*